# postgis / proj 900913 to 4326 projection issues with Y coordinate

Tags: gis, projection, postgis, proj4js, proj

this is an oldie, but i cannot seem to find a solution.

When i want to do an st_transform on a 900913 coordinate to a 4326 system, the y coordinate shifts.

example:

SELECT
AsText(
Transform(
Transform(
GeomFromText( 'POINT( 449760.25168159 6790560.4594059 )', 900913),
4326
),
900913
)
)

here the original 900913 stating point is st_stransformed to 4326 and back to 900913. the result is not the original point, y differs. (i will insert the result later, i don't have it here).

i tried altering the proj4text for 4326, adding +nadgrids=@null like i read somewhere

the proj4text for srid 4326 is currently:

"select proj4text from spatial_ref_sys where srid=4326"
 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

the proj4text for srid 900913 is currently:

"select proj4text from spatial_ref_sys where srid=900913"
 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m 
 +nadgrids=@null +no_defs

i also tried doing a projection from 900913 to another projection to 4326, but i get the exact same point as a direct transformation from 900913 to 4326.

anyone any ideas?

EJ

Comment: You might have better luck on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

EPSG:900913 is ill-defined projection. You should use EPSG:3857 instead, which should be exactly the same Spherical Mercator but a standardized one.

Any reprojection is a lossy operation. Converting a coordinate back and forth is going to make noise in last binary digits, which are usually sub-millimeter error.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PostGIS are you using? I've tried the query with this configuration: `POSTGIS="1.5.2" GEOS="3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009"` and it works fine.

Despite that, I've red some problems involving 900913 coordinates.